# Where does the Stand Still feat stop movement?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, movement, opportunity-attack

[Stand Still](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/stand-still-combat-final/) lets you stop somebody's movement when you make an attack of opportunity against them. If an adjacent opponent moves out of a square adjacent to you (without withdrawing or otherwise evading the AoO) and you use Stand Still, does a successful hit stop them in the adjacent square or in the next square?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## In the adjacent square

I can't find any specific clarification for this conclusion, so I based it on the way basic attacks of opportunity work.

Attacks of opportunity use your normal range, therefore they have to consider the enemy to be in a square where you can target them normally, not the square they want to move to. This implies that the AoO is resolved before the remainder of the triggering move, therefore the rule that states they cannot move any further during their turn comes into effect before they leave your adjacent square.

This fits with my intuitive understanding of how the feat is supposed to work. After all, if they could move a bit further it wouldn't be very "still".

Comment: I’m about 90% sure there’s an explicit statement somewhere that says that attacks of opportunity occur before the provoking action—in this case, moving out of that square—and thus the target would still be in the square they were trying to leave. +1 either way, since this is the correct answer and your reasoning for why it must be is sound, but I recommend trying to do some digging to find that explicit statement.

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65429/can-you-be-tripped-by-an-aoo-while-standing-up

Comment: [The only phrasing I could find is](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) "An attack of opportunity “interrupts” the normal flow of actions in the round. If an attack of opportunity is provoked, immediately resolve the attack of opportunity, then continue with the next character’s turn (or complete the current turn, if the attack of opportunity was provoked in the midst of a character’s turn)." This agrees with this (you interrupt the action when you make the attack)